# Save csv as xlsx

Tags: excel, csv, vba

Can anyone help?

Is there a possibilty to convert multiple .csv files to xlsx but keeping all the data inact? I mean when I use the below code the output xlsx file is messed up. There are no column all data is as text.

I am currently using this

```
Sub CopyDataFromCSTR()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim myPath As String
  Dim myFile As String
  Dim myExtension As String

  'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  'Set folder's path to search within
  myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

  'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.csv*"

  'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    wb.SaveAs myPath & Replace(myFile, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wb.Close False

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
  Loop

  MsgBox ("Done!")

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  'Release garbage
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: can you rephrase "There are no column all data is as text." That reads as nonsense.

Comment: I mean that before coverting the files data was in several columns. After saving as xlsx the data was squeezed into one column A

Comment: gotcha. What happens if you manually open one of these CSV files (before converting) in Excel. Do they go into multiple columns then?

Comment: when I manually open those csv files, the layout is as original, that is, data is in various columns respectively